# Spring Boot i18n issue

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-boot, internationalization

I am learning spring Boot framework right now, I am trying to apply i18n concept on my simple application. But whenever I run the application, the following error returned: `"No message found under code 'label.welcomeMessage' for locale 'en_US'."`. I have read about this issue and tried a lot before I getting here to ask but noting have worked with me.

Here is my AppClass configuration:

```
package com.abed.main.configuration;


import java.util.Locale;

import org.springframework.context.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.LocaleResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.InterceptorRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver;

@Configuration
public class AppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer{



    @Bean
    public LocaleResolver localeResolver()
    {
        SessionLocaleResolver slr = new SessionLocaleResolver();
        slr.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
        return slr ; 
    }

    @Bean
    public LocaleChangeInterceptor LocaleChangeInterceptor()
    {
        LocaleChangeInterceptor lci = new LocaleChangeInterceptor();
        lci.setParamName("lang");
        return lci ;
    }
    {

    }
    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {

        registry.addInterceptor(LocaleChangeInterceptor());


    }


    @Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource() {
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource msgSrc = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        msgSrc.setBasename("classpath:messages/ticket");
        msgSrc.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        return msgSrc;
    }

}
```

Here is the welcome JSP:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
    <%@ taglib prefix = "c" uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
     <%@ taglib prefix = "spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>


<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title><spring:message code="label.welcomePageTitle"></spring:message></title>
</head>
<body>

<h1><spring:message code="label.welcomeMessage"></spring:message></h1>
<form action="ticket" method="GET">
<spring:message code="label.ticketId"></spring:message><input type="text" name="Student_Id">
<input type="submit" value="<spring:message code="label.search"></spring:message>">
</form>

<a href="createTicket"><spring:message code="label.createTicketSubmit"></spring:message></a>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the hierarchy of my application:

[image: Application hierarchy]

Any Help Please , Thanks in advance

Comment: You should have a `ticket.properties` for the default values. Also Spring Boot already configures a `MessageSource` so why not simply use that one? Finally I would suggest NOT to use JSP but rather something like Thymeleaf for your views (much more flexible and less restrictive then JSP especially with embedded container).

Comment: i just did as you commented , but it is still the same problem. i appreciate your comment so much , my next step is to do it using  Thymeleaf

Comment: I test your code many time. Every thing is correct ! and welcome page is show with out error. maybe you got mistake in your message file syntax!!

Answer (score 1):

You need to configuration a `bean` named `messageSource` 
here is the code, add it to a `java` code file, make sure `@Configuration` can be scan:

```
@Configuration
public class MessageSourceConfig {

    @Bean(name = "messageSource")
    public ResourceBundleMessageSource getMessageSource() throws Exception {
        ResourceBundleMessageSource resourceBundleMessageSource = new ResourceBundleMessageSource();
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasenames("i18n/messages");
        return resourceBundleMessageSource;
    }
}
```

The point is : `resourceBundleMessageSource.setBasenames("i18n/messages");`
remember the base path is `classpath`, so the `i18n` properties resource should set in `i18n/messages`. In order not to crash problem, I suggest you create the properties by using `IDEA`.

Quote Spring official doc:

> Strategy interface for resolving messages, with support for the parameterization and internationalization of such messages.
>   Spring provides two out-of-the-box implementations for production:
>   `ResourceBundleMessageSource`, built on top of the standard ResourceBundle
>   `ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource`, being able to reload message definitions without restarting the VM.

This is the reason we need to configure a bean named `messageSource`.